# Update program: overwrite files?

Tags: python, pyqt, auto-update

I'm developing a software and I want, for several reasons, to develop my own auto-update feature. The program is a full GUI, written with PyQt, and uses icons, data files, etc. It will be frozen with cx_freeze or pyinstaller.

The auto-update part will download the new version (a zip) on a remote server. Then, it gets complicated:

The software is running, and has downloaded the new version. What does it do with the new version ? Can the software extract the files from the zip, and overwrite the files of the running version ?

Or should I store the new version aside, quit the running version, and somehow use the new version ? If so, how do I do the exchange between the old and new version ?

EDIT:

Here is for example the `closeEvent` method of my class QMainWindow:

```
def closeEvent(self, event):

    """Method to perform actions before exiting.
    Allows to save the prefs in a file"""

    ...Do some stuff...

    QtGui.qApp.quit()

    self.logger.info("Closing the program")
```

Can I use this method to perform the exchange ?

Comment: Open a thread without `deamon` remove old files, later extract new. But need compare every configuration files for missing/invalid parameters. Of course kill all related applications before starting new !

Comment: I edited my question to be more accurate, if it helps. Could you show me how and where I should open the thread ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549331/pyqt-application-performing-updates) to yours and the accepted answer says:

> After downloading the installer for the newer version, you can use
>   [`atexit.register()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html#atexit.register) with [`os.exec*()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os#os.execl) to run the installer,
>   e.g. `atexit.register(os.execl, "installer.exe", "installer.exe")`.
>   This will make the installer start when the application is about to
>   exit. The application will immediately exit after the `os.exec*()`
>   call, so no race condition will occur.

Looks like a good solution for your use-case